# how to override the default style of bootstrap for some section of the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website and now I had decided to add bootstrap styles to the website, but if I include bootstrap in the master page it make all the style messed up, so how can I use bootstrap features along my previous style sheet. as if I will over ride bootstrap css it make changes to all the elements.

my problem is that i am trying to show a modal popup and i want it to have bootstrap style but I don't want my rest of the page to get affected by it.

please help me with this...

Comment: Try loading the bootstrap.css file(s) first then loading your custom stylesheet(s) afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

To Solve this problem i had created a new css file and included it on the page and then i made the property of the class to imortant in order to override the default property of the class.

below is sample code for it

```
input[type="text"]
{
  border:none !important;
  height:20px !important;
  color: #E0E0E0;
}
```

so in the above code i have overridden two properties one is border and height, you can override as many as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize bootstrap before downloading it, maybe you can take just what you need (just modal popup for example): http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html

Comment: Thanks for the help,  but what if i want to update the bootstrap to a new version after some time or some other team member will try to do the same. i think it will be a bigger problem at that time